# Is it possible to pass PCI express data signals via an express card USB 3.0 adapter?

Tags: windows, usb, pci-express, serial-port, usb-controller

I have a [Magideal Dual Ports HUB PCI-E USB 3.0 Express Card Adapter](https://www.amazon.in/dp/B0787B2K96) that I use as a PCIe to USB 3.0 adapter.

I want to connect an external GPU (as a PCI express device) via a USB 3.0 cable which only carry PCIe signals to the adapter. My GPU is connected to a riser with a USB 3.0 cable as connector. It looks like this model:

[image]

But the problem here is that the adapter only accept usb devices and my Windows 10 throws an error as:

> "USB device not recognized."

Is there any software method (e.g. changing USB host controller) to only pass or proxy the raw data signals to the parent PCI express bus, so that my computer recognizes it as a PCI device.

This is the connection tree when I connect a USB 2.0 flash drive to the adapter:

[image]

Comment: my gpu is connected to a riser with usb 3.0 cable as connector

Comment: yes it is, that interface only transfer pcie signlas and doesn't work as a real usb port.

Comment: @Fuad that riser is "just" using the USB 3 connectors to transfer a PCIe signal, it is not running as USB 3. They use similar enough type of signals that the cable is broadly compatible with both, but they do not use the same protocol or anything else. That does not mean that USB 3 is natively PCIe and can connect a GPU to any old cable or connection.

Comment: I am searching for a way that make my adapter usb port to only transfer raw data and power

Comment: Why does it seem like everyone is downvoting questions just because their answer is "No"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is there any software method (e.g. changing USB host controller) to only pass or proxy the raw data signals to the parent PCI express bus, so that my computer recognizes it as a PCI device.

*In theory* it would be possible, as that's exactly what Thunderbolt/USB4 does, but you won't be able to make a basic USB3 host controller behave that way. "Changing the USB host controller" is not a software method, as the controller found in your card is a purpose-made ASIC and is not fully reprogrammable; the chance of it having a direct pass-through mode is nearly 0.

It might be much easier to cut out the USB3 controller entirely and wire your "PCIe cable" directly to the PCIe slot inside the ExpressCard bay (presumably the same way as is done on the eGPU side).

Either way, though, your x16 eGPU would also be limited to an x1 PCIe connection, both on the ExpressCard side and through the USB3 cable.

Answer (score 2):

In order to use efficiently an external GPU (eGPU) you need to transfer
data at high speeds. Thunderbolt 3 for example supports up to 40Gbps,
while USB3 ports only allow 5/10/20 Gbps, and the protocol is also
different and unusable.

For a satisfactory solution that is not under-powered,
you need either a PCIe-based solution or USB4, which are built for this
speed and can have the necessary number of data lanes.
USB3 solutions might only be able to support lower-range GPUs.
A self-powered enclosure might also be necesary.

If your computer has spare M.2 or mPCIe slots that you can use,
you can find eGPU docks that plug into such a slot, but some work
might be required inside the computer case.

An external GPU dock contains a PCIe port for the graphics card with
either a Thunderbolt or USB-C cable.
Some examples of such enclosures can be found on
[Amazon](https://www.amazon.com/egpu/s?k=egpu),
but they are not cheap.

Note that USB4 can contain PCIe encapsulation as an optional feature.
That feature is sometimes called "Thunderbolt capable USB4".

The speed of your CPU might also be a factor in your ability to use
or choose a given eGPU enclosure and a given GPU card.

You will find many resources on the internet for any question about
eGPU. The external graphics card community is found on
[egpu.io](https://egpu.io/).

Another random article which could clarify the concepts is
[9 Things You Need to Know About External GPUs](https://www.makeuseof.com/tag/everything-need-know-external-gpu/).